# Making countdown function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, gettime, jquery

I am newbie and need ur help. I have a problem on finding out days, hours, minutes and seconds. I dont know what to update minutes after seconds will reach 60 and same with hours and days.
I am trying to countdown to a given date in a format of Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds.
[Here is the link of what I've done so far.](http://jsbin.com/apuhep/7)
Thnx in advance! :)

Comment: It looks like it's a math problem not a programming problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your `count_execution` function and added some comments. It should do what you ask.

```
function count_execution() {
  // target date of event
  var eventDate   = new Date(settings.date);
  // now
  var currentDate = new Date();
  // get date diff *in milliseconds*
  var diff   = Math.abs(currentDate - eventDate);

  // compute days left
  // 24h * 60m * 60s * 1000 = 86400000
  var days = Math.floor(diff / 86400000);
  diff = diff % 86400000;

  // compute hours left
  // 60m * 60s * 1000 = 3600000
  var hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600000);
  diff = diff % 3600000;

  // the same for minutes
  var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 60000);
  diff = diff % 60000;

 // finally, seconds
 var seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000);

 $this.find('#days').text(days);
 $this.find('#hours').text(hours);
 $this.find('#mins').text(minutes);
 $this.find('#secs').text(seconds);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ye, I got what I wanted, but is there an easier way of getting hours, minutes and seconds using jQuery?

Comment: I think that probably your best bet would be using a jQuery plugin like @Mohammed suggested. Strictly speaking about date manipulation and formatting I recently discovered [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) and it's been very useful to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
var seconds = 1355998990 - new Date().getTime(), // whatever
minutes = Math.floor(seconds/60),
hours = Math.floor(minutes/60),
days = Math.floor(hours/24);

seconds %= 60;
minutes %= 60;
hours %= 24;

console.log("d: " + days + " h: " + hours + " m: " + minutes + " s: " + seconds);
```

Will this do?

Also make sure to check out [this](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html); maybe you can get some inspiration there.

Comment: Awesome clocks! also, What is console.log() ?

Comment: console.log() will directly log into the Chrome Debug Console and Firebug Console. For quickly checking what variable values are :)

Answer (score 2):

why don't you use one of the many plugins available to do the trick, consider the following links:

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

this one is listing many plugins for the same purpose, use any of them and smile :)
http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/01/jquery-countdown-scripts.html